# Android: Container XML Layout wrap weight and fill height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have been battling for a couple of days trying to create a custom layout in Android divided in 3 parts, a "vote" counter container that displays the amount of people that voted a message, a text message container that will contain the text and the author of a message and a button container that will be used to vote up or down a message.

So far I have this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/containerInner"
    >

    <!-- # VOTES CONTAINER -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/containerVotes"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/votesPost"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- MESSAGE CONTAINER -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/containerText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/containerVotes"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/titleGlobus"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/AutorGlobus"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:maxWidth="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleGlobus"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- VOTE UP/DOWN CONTAINER -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/containerButtons"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/containerText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/containerText"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/containerButtonUp"
            >

            <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                app:cb_color="@color/white"
                app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip"
                android:id="@+id/upvote_button"
                />

         </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/containerButtonDown"
            android:layout_below="@+id/containerButtonUp"
            >

            <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                app:cb_color="@color/white"
                app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
                android:id="@+id/downvote_button"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The Layout I am getting in the phone using the above code is this:

[image: Pre]

And I want to achieve this:

[image: Post]

So there are two main things that I need to achieve here:

- Make the RelativeLayout *containerText* fill the whole height of its superior container.
- Alight the Author name to the right of the container, but aligned just at the end of the "message" TextView.

I have been trying to fix the fix issue changing the height of the *containerText* container to fill_parent without success, changing all the way up to the main container all the height properties to fill_parent.

If I try to align the author name to the right using alignParentRight=true , the RelativeLayout then takes the whole space of the screen, pushing out the buttons container. I have also tried changing the way I am positioning the different layouts respect others, changing the toLeftOf or toRightTo, with terrible results.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am stuck with this issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!-- MESSAGE CONTAINER -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        <!-- Set this height  to match_parent -->
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/containerText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/containerVotes"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/titleGlobus"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/AutorGlobus"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:maxWidth="180dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"

            <!-- Removed below tag and added alignParentBottom and alignParentRight -->
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Inserting the ' android:layout_alignParentRight="true" ' makes the textview to fill the whole width -> giving this output: http://imgur.com/a/a5EkB

Removing the layout_below makes it appear to the right of the message, as if the layout couldn't grow vertically.

Comment: Have you added alignParentBottom? It should stick it to the bottom of the container

Comment: yes, I changed the match_parent in the layout_height  and added alignParentBottom and alignParentRight,  but I am getting the image I posted in the last comment.

Comment: This looks really strange, try adding alignParentBottom to the message container as well